# CQL escape \xa0

Tags: unicode, cassandra, cql

I have a row in cassandra table where one of the column has a trailing space which looks like "someval\xa0"

How can i write a cql query to escape the unicode character \xa0, basically i'm trying to delete the row from the table.

Tried with \, single quotes, $$$ but no luck..

```
delete * from testkeyspace.testtable where username="someval\xa0"
delete * from testkeyspace.testtable where username=$$$someval\xa0$$$
delete * from testkeyspace.testtable where username=\\someval\xa0\\
```

Answer (score 0):

Text constants should be wrapped into single quotes: `'someval\xa0'` (see [doc for reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/valid_literal_r.html)).

Comment: So, when i have the query like select * from testkeyspace.testtable where username='someval\xa0'; does not seem to return the record.... I meant retuning empty rows..